# align text center not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap framework and I've created a column in which I've used `text-align:center;` css property on two elements and there are not aligned the same and I don't understand why. 
Here's the markup:

```
 <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail-header">
        <h1>Brand</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-content">
        <ul>
          <li>Identity</li>
          <li>Strategy Brand</li>
          <li>Identity Manual</li>
          <li>Guide Brand</li> 
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
```

'text-center' class has `text-align:center;` css property.

And here is a working fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pQ4F/)

Can someone explain me why those elements are not aligned properly ?

Comment: try putting `padding:0` in your `<ul>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the default left padding on the `<ul>`

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pQ4F/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of using `.text-center` Helper class use the `.center-block` for centering an element in bootstrap because this helper class use `margin` and `display` css properties for cenetering the element